# how can i transfer my app on one app store account to another

Tags: ios, app-store, ioc-container

When i transfer my MacOS app from one apple account to another apple account then something went wrong like this

[image]

Note : My app is contain safari extension so, whats problem please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: The message tells you what the problem is. Your app has a shared group entitlement so it cannot be transferred. Even if you aren't using the shared group, the mere presence of the entitlement prevents the transfer

Comment: @Paulw11 without shared group entitlement app is not working because my app is totally depend on share group. Thak you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that once the app has the entitlement included, an app transfer will not be possible, even if you submit a new version without the entitlement. However, you can transfer the app via the binary reassigned process.

By completing this process, the app will effectively be a new and separate app on the Mac App Store. This is of course extremely inconvenient for us, but there's not really anything to do about it :)

For More Info please check : https://github.com/electron/electron-osx-sign/issues/150#issuecomment-330778870